# Custom Simple Membership Provider .Net 4.5 without SQL installed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using Rest Service to authenticate against my users and do not want to use any kind of local/remote database as membership provider.

I am getting this error while initializing simple membership provider.
The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized.

This is my config and i left connectionstring section blank.
Do I need to install sql express to make it work?

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MyMembershipProvider"  type="_1822Style.Models.CustomMembershipProvider"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```